# Do ECS health checks have access to image env variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I am using a build argument passed in to my Dockerfile during a build command. This argument sets an env var in the container.

If I define a health check in my ECS Task Definition, will it be able to access the env var that I have set using the build arg when running the command using CMD or CMD-SHELL?

I'd like to do this so that the value can just be set during the building of the container and not something that I'd need to hardcode in my Terraform code.

Comment: Any environment variable available to the main docker process in your ECS task should also be available to the health check process.